# ActiveMQ C++ Synchronous consumer

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

There are some [code samples](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/example.html) for ActiveMQ C++ Client, which are asynchronous. What I am looking for is synchronous consumer. I just want to send and get messages. The code I have pointed out uses asynchronous and not sure how to make a synchronous class out of it.

[MessageConsumer](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/api_docs/activemqcpp-3.2.5/html/classcms_1_1_message_consumer.html) class indicates that there is a synchronous call, ie: recieve().
When i call this on my object it fails as follows, how can i fix this? how can i just call a recieve from queue.

```
ActiveMQConsumer.cc: In member function `virtual void ActiveMQConsumer::getMessage()':
ActiveMQConsumer.cc:62: error: 'class cms::MessageConsumer' has no member named 'recieve'
In file included from ActiveMQWrapper.cc:29:
ActiveMQConsumer.cc: In member function `virtual void ActiveMQConsumer::getMessage()':
ActiveMQConsumer.cc:62: error: 'class cms::MessageConsumer' has no member named 'recieve'
ActiveMQWrapper.cc: In static member function `static std::string ActiveMQWrapper::get()':
ActiveMQWrapper.cc:58: error: base operand of `->' has non-pointer type `ActiveMQConsumer'
```

and here is the code:

```
void ActiveMQWrapper::get(){

        std:string brokerURI = "tcp://localhost:61613?wireFormat=stomp";

        ActiveMQConsumer consumer( brokerURI);
        consumer->getMessage();
}

// ActiveMQConsumer class code is following

virtual void getMessage() {

        try {

            auto_ptr<ConnectionFactory> connectionFactory(ConnectionFactory::createCMSConnectionFactory( brokerURI ) );
            connection = connectionFactory->createConnection();
            connection->start();
            session = connection->createSession( Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );
            destination = session->createQueue( "TEST.Prototype" );
            consumer = session->createConsumer( destination );
            std::cout<<consumer->recieve();
        } catch( CMSException& e ) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two errors are because receive is misspelled: Change `std::cout<<consumer->recieve();` to `std::cout<<consumer->receive();`

The last error is because `consumer` is being used as a pointer:  Change the line `consumer->getMessage();` to `consumer.getMessage();`