# Activemq C++ request-response

Tags: c++, activemq-classic

I started to work with Activemq-cpp and used the asychronous client that is available as [example](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/example.html).
But now I want to implement a request-response, i.e. the producer starts sending a message to the consumer and waits for the response. The consumer gets the message, changes it and sends back to the producer.
The consumer has a [receive option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141245/activemq-c-synchronous-consumer), but I have no idea how to configure both for request-response, especially the producer.

I appriciate any help. Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you implemented it - request/reply pattern with CMS library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CMS client is a porting of JMS to C++ and as such the [examples](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html) that explain how to do JMS Request / Response are easy to port to the C++ client.

The basic structure is that on the request side the client must create a producer to send the request and a consumer to process the response.  The consumer should be created and be listening on the target response destination prior to sending the request.  On the responder side a consumer is created that reads from the request Queue and does its work and when done it creates a producer that sends a response to the destination specified in the ReplyTo property of the incoming request.